# calculate $\iiint_S {z{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}dxdydz$ in the domain $S$ between $x^2+y^2=1$, $z=0$, $z=x$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Calculate $\iiint_S {z{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}\,dx\,dy\,dz$ in the domain $S$ between $ x^2+y^2=1$,  $z=0$, $z=x$, ($z\ge0$).

I tried transformation to cylindrical coordinates, but I go the result $0$ instead of $\frac{π}{20}$ which is the correct answer, according to my textbook.

Answer (score 4):

According to cylindrical coordinates,

[http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CylindricalCoordinates.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhwFc.gif)

$x=rcos\theta$

$y=rsin\theta$

$z=z$

So you will have:

$0<r<1$

$0<\theta<2\pi$

$0<z<rcos\theta$

The jacobian of this transformation is r, so we can transform the integral as:

$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\int_0^{rcos\theta} \frac{1}{2}zr^2\;dz\;dr\;d\theta=\frac{\pi}{20}$

Answer (score 1):

$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_0^1 \int_0^{r  cos(\theta)} z r^2 dz dr d\theta = \frac{\pi}{20}$

Comment: why is $0<θ<2π$ and not $-π<θ<0$ ?

Comment: $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ is a circle, so the angle is $0$ to $2\pi$.

Comment: We dont want the full circle, just semi circle, that is $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$. If you make a simple plot you will understand what I am saying.

Comment: When we take the square root of $y^2 = 1 - x^2$, we get both $y = \sqrt {1-x^2}$ and $y = - \sqrt {1-x^2}$.

Comment: I think I see what you are getting at, @ChristosI.; my answer includes it.

Comment: If you take the integral for $\theta$ from $\frac{-\pi}{2} <= x <= \frac{\pi}{2}$, it yields the same answer as the $\frac{1}{2}$ accounts for the half-domain.

Comment: Eh...it actually only works the right way basically by coincidence, because the sign of the integrand happens to be the same as the sign of $z$, so the limits going in the wrong direction cancels out with the sign change in the integrand. That wouldn't work under other circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

If you interpret the question as giving the bounds $x^2+y^2 \leq 1,0 \leq z \leq x$, then you also infer $x \geq 0$ from the latter, which gives the cylindrical coordinate bounds $0 \leq r \leq 1,-\pi/2 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2,0 \leq z \leq r \cos(\theta)$. (Alternately you can make the $\theta$ domain $[0,\pi/2] \cup [3\pi/2,2 \pi]$ but that is annoying.)